# I'm unable to configure JavaFx SDK path in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am unable to configure JavaFX SDK path in its preferences, but I dragged lib/desktop jars to my workspace buildpath. But eclipse can't recognize `import javafx.application.Application;`. In which jar can I find that?

This is my SDK path: `D:\Program Files\JavaFX\javafx-sdk1.3`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the old 1.x version of JavaFX? If not then locate the **jfxrt.jar** file in a file system and add  it to your project's classpath.